# Minicom - How do I store the newline delay setting?

Tags: serial-console, minicom

In Minicom, I prefer to change my `Newline tx delay (ms)` setting via `CTRL-A T` to incorporate some delay between newlines, usually 100ms. That way there is a delay when I am pasting something into a serial console. How can I store this setting?

Currently I need to set it every time I open a minicom instance. I would have thought that this setting would be located inside the minicom configuration, but it seems to be more of a runtime setting.